# Read file from a remote location with java

Tags: java

I have some doubts about the way to read file from a remote (inside our network) location with java. I'm developing a simple java application from a windows machine and I'm able to reach a remote file that resides on a unix machine in this way:

```
File fileToRead=new File(new URI(file:////192.168.0.27/export/myFile.txt))
```

With the same application my collegue that is using kubuntu to develop is not able to reach the file. I get FileNotFoundException.

What can be the problem?

**UPDATE 1**
I would want to use jcfis to solve my problem, but in this cas the application will work both on windows than on linux?

Comment: First, probably "file:" is not correct.  If the file is remote, then you need "ftp:" or "http:" or some other protocol.  Second, I'd guess you also need a `Socket` class, not `File`.

Comment: Windows is probably defaulting to using Samba/CIFS to access the file, while kubuntu has no handler for the `file://` protocol.

Comment: see this question about file: URLs: http://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved using a [jcifs](https://jcifs.samba.org/) library in the following way

```
SmbFile fileToRead= new SmbFile(smb://192.168.0.27/export/myFile.txt);
```

This works in both developing environment (Windows and Linux)

Comment: jcifs is deprecated. Refer to newer jcifs-ng: https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT: The OP has specified which protocol he would want to use. This answer fails to use that said protocol so it is not valid anymore.

Use a URL object instead:

```
URL url = new URL("http://someaddress.com/somefile.txt");
```

With this URL, you can open a InputStream:

```
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Which you can read with a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

EDIT: This will work fine assuming HTTP can be used to download the file.

Full code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://someaddress.com");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
// You can read lines like this
String line = br.readLine();
```

Comment: This presupposes that http is a workable protocol for opening this file.  It very well may not be.

Comment: In my case URL url = new URL("http://someaddress.com") could become URL url = new URL("file://192.168.0.27/export/myFile.txt)")?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I've added your comment to the post. The OP specified no protocol in particular so I made a assumption.

Comment: @Skizzo Try it, but you will need to tell us more about what protocol you can use to transfer the file. If you have none, then good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FTP or HTTP you can directly use @AlphSpirit's answer. Otherwise you can use the `java.net.Socket` and implement your own protocol (which is easier than using FTP or HTTP, you will need a `java.net.ServerSocket` running on the other machine).

**Edit:** You said you would like to use JCFIS as it works both on Windows and Linux, but the JRE does too.